# Adding LinkedIn SDK in android studio error: "Configuration with name 'default' not found"

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am developing an application to login with `LinkedIn`. 
The things I have done are:

- Downloaded `LinkedIn` SDK from this  [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk)
- Copied the `LinkedIn-SDK` from that downloaded project and added it in my project-> libs folder.
- Added:

  - `compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk')`   to `build.gradle` and
  - `include ':libs:linkedin-sdk'`   to `setting.gradle` files

Then I am getting an error as:

`"Gradle 'LinkdinApplication' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."`

while building project.

So, Is the procedure that I followed is right? or How should I add it?

Comment: https://github.com/mukesh4u/Android-LinkedIn-Demo

Comment: @quicklearner: I have followed the same procedure as said in the LinkedIn console and my problem is with adding the library in my project. So can you please help me on doing that?

Comment: you are using android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: i am using android studio

Answer (score 6):

After many searching over the Internet, I finally managed to import linkedin SDK.

In my app dependencies, instead of setting

```
compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk')
```

I put

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['linkedin-sdk'])
```

And magically Android Studio imported without problems the library.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is because the **robolectric** plugin. With the release of Robolectric 3.0, this plugin is no longer needed to run tests with Gradle. Please refer to http://robolectric.org/getting-started for instructions on how to get started with Gradle and Android Studio.

My **build.gradle** in linkedin-sdk folder:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
         setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Then I am getting another build error as Error:(18, 0) Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists.

Comment: @Hari Krishnan. Have you copied my build.gradle fully?

Comment: Yes and the response now is - "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."

Comment: @Hari Krishan Have you tried to remove completelly robolectric plugin from linkedin library to find out reason of error?

Comment: sorry i cant get you. "robolectric plugin" is a new term for me.

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: finally, it is now solved. busted by ass on this Linkedin- I'm disappointed !! I Think they should simply add a gradle dependency of their own instead of downloading a zip file

Comment: @Gal Rom. Totally agree with you)

Comment: hello @HariKrishnan I'm facing the same problem . how did you solve that.. please help

Answer (score 0):

Android studio projects has two libs folders /libs and /app/libs. use the /libs folder to add linkedin-sdk.

- compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk') to build.gradle and
- include':libs:linkedin-sdk' to setting.gradle files

this works perfectly.