# How to add linkedin mobile sdk to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I'm working on an app in which I need to integrate facebook and LinkedIn.

I'm done with facebook integration and I've registered my app on linkedin and i've downloaded the mobile sdk for linkedin but don't now how to add it to android studio so that i can use the classes of linkedin sdk.

Please help I've searched a lot dint find any solution regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To add linkedin-sdk to AndroidStudio:

1) Downloaded LinkedIn-SDK.

2) Copy the downloaded LinkedIn-SDK and add it in yourProject-> libs folder.

3) Add: `compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk')` to `build.gradle`

and

`include ':libs:linkedin-sdk'` to `setting.gradle` files.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the response.. I've tried this but it gives an error. says
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: @ManishNegi You're welcome, maybe you have another lib/plugin that cause this error... check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32776618/4224337)

Comment: I dint get it why do i need to download someother plugins?

Comment: Try to compile with "gradle tasks --info", and check the log.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386395/how-to-add-linkedin-sdk-path-in-app-gradle